# Adding Videos to YouTube Using SharePoint

Tags: javascript, vb.net, video, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I know I can embed YouTube videos into SharePoint, however I want users to be able to do everything from the SharePoint site: both upload and play videos. Is there existing code that you all know of that might help me accomplish this? If not, a conceptual idea on how I might accomplish this would be great too!

My goal is to have users upload a video with some metadata (author, video title, date taken, location, etc) and have that video be uploaded under profile 'X' in YouTube with a title of 'video title - location' and no description. The video will then automatically be linked to SharePoint with the additional metadata. Users can than click the embedded video to expand and play it (or have it link them to the YouTube page).

Hopefully you all can give me a push in the right direction.

Oh and I plan on doing any coding in JavaScript or VB.net (however I can always just convert it from C#).

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very big, but in few lines :

- Upload you video in a docLib
- Develope an event receiver on your docLib (itemAdded/ItemUpdated //event in asynch => Warning with the chekedIn - CheckedOut event it will raise twice your ItemUpdated)
- In you Receiver, get all your metaData from your Item (author, title, date...) Upload your Video to youtube using the [Youtube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_dotnet#Direct_Upload)

hope this line will help you